# Remote SSH Gnu/Linux server isn't recognizing my pipe

Tags: ssh, grep, tail

Basically I'm trying to run the following command:

```
sshpass -p "xxx" ssh root@x.x.x.x "tail -f /tmp/messages | grep ptp4l" | cat -n > output.txt
```

I'm trying to get tmp/messages to continually write to a local file so some of our techs can continually monitor IEEE 1588v2 offsets from their master without having to understand anything about the Gnu/Linux server they're accessing.

When I run this command I get no output, to my file at all.

When I manually run the command:

```
tail -f /tmp/messages | grep ptp4l
```

all is good and I have no problems at all. I get the output that I'm looking for.

Am I missing anything? Can you not send a pipe through a quoted command?

Thanks,
Stephen

Comment: This may be an issue with sshpass not handling the ssh command correctly - did you try `sshpass -p "xxxx" ssh root@x.x.x.x bash -c "tail -f /tmp/messages | grep ptp4l"`. Alternatively, did you try using public-key authentication instead of password authentication?

Answer (score 3):

This is the classical "writing to a pipe is fully buffered" problem.

Try either forcing your `ssh` to allocate a pseudo-tty on the remote machine with `-tt` or use the `--line-buffered` option to `grep`, if it accepts that option.

```
ssh ... -tt </dev/null 'tail -f /tmp/messages | grep ptp4l' | cat -n > output.txt

ssh ... 'tail -f /tmp/messages | grep --line-buffered ptp4l' | cat -n > output.txt
```

The `</dev/null` redirection when allocating a tty on the remote machine is in order to prevent `ssh` from messing with the *local* tty (by putting it in raw mode), which is a side effect of the `-t` switch. You can do that with any ssh command which is not using the stdin (if necessary, the ssh client will open `/dev/tty` to read its password, it will not use stdin for that).